# Do health departments inform hospitals/clinics of disease trends?

Tags: epidemiology

For example, during a common cold epidemic, do doctors get reported beforehand that there is a trend going on so that they can use this information to suspect diagnosis?
Does every health care unit have a special website where physicians log on to, to see these disease trends?

Comment: This seems to be off-topic here, maybe try  https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/  , it **might** be on-topic there (I don't know). Please ask on their meta site first!

Comment: Sorry. Where can I find their meta site?

Comment: First make your account there, then it should be visible. On the top menu, at the extreme right, you should find it.